# Integrating jquery isotope with Foundation

Tags: responsive-design, jquery-isotope, zurb-foundation

have managed to get jQuery Isotope and Zurb Foundation playing reasonably nicely but for some reason, at certain widths, when there is plenty of room for three columns (there should always be room in Foundation's responsive grid), only one or two columns display.

Here is a link to an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yraxh

Has anyone managed to get an example of this working with Foundation or Twitter Bootstrap, so that it works nicely within their grid?

Thanks.

Comment: I've since found that this is a bug with how JS rounds up the numbers. One way to resolve is to use columns of slightly too narrow widths (ex: 33.2%) and then figure out a way to cover up the gaps.

Answer (score 2):

I would also give "Packery" a try. It works better with percentage based layouts. It does not have all of the same features as Isotope but will most likely serve its purpose.

http://packery.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look but am a bit frightened to touch it with the current project which is working OK! Maybe with the next...